# Laravel RFC email compliance when using BCC fields

Tags: php, email, laravel-4, swiftmailer

I know this is common, but cannot see any clear answers.

Here is the code:

```
$message->to('admin@website.com', 'All Users')
  ->bcc('test@hotmail.com,test2@hotmail.com', 'name,name2')
  ->subject(Input::get('emailsubject'));
```

This throws this error:

```
Address in mailbox given [test@hotmail.com,test2@hotmail.com] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.
```

If i simply use one email it works fine, how should I be creating my array for the list?

It currently looks like this when pulling from the DB:

```
  $query = DB::table('users')->get();
  $bcclist = "";
  $bccnamelist = "";
  foreach ($query as $key=>$user) {
    if (filter_var($user->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $bcclist .= $user->email.",";
        $bccnamelist .= $user->username.",";
    }
  }
```

Then using it:

```
->bcc($bcclist, $bccnamelist)
```

How should the emails be formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel uses SwiftMailer under the hood, so it'd be an array:

```
// without names
->bcc(['test@hotmail.com', 'test2@hotmail.com'])

// with names
->bcc(['test@hotmail.com' => 'name','test2@hotmail.com' => 'name2'])
```

From the looks of things, you can generate this array with `array_combine($bcclist, $bccnamelist)`.

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#setting-cc-recipients